# Azure Certificate export script giving error

Tags: azure, certificate, ssl-certificate

Running this Microsoft Provided script [Link to MS Blog Post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/02/24/creating-a-local-pfx-copy-of-app-service-certificate/) to export your SSL certificate to PFX file keeps producing this error on this line.

Line: $certificateProperties=Get-Member -InputObject $ascResource.Properties.certificates[0] -MemberType NoteProperty

Error: Get-Member : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet. At C:\Users\User\Desktop\certget.ps1:14 char:24 + ... eProperties=Get-Member -InputObject $ascResource.Properties.certifica ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [Get-Member], InvalidOperationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoObjectInGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetMemberCommand

Anyone else come across this error and find a way to fix it?  Thanks!

Comment: is  $ascResource variable not empty?

Comment: Thank you for the response.  That Variable seems to work: $ascResource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceName $appServiceCertificateName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType "Microsoft.CertificateRegistration/certificateOrders" -ApiVersion "2015-08-01"

Comment: ... but does it contain anything?

Comment: well, just check if `.Properties` contain anything. so do `$ascResource.Properties`

Comment: $ascResource.Properties and $ascResource.Properties.certificates both give me outputs that look correct

$ascResource.Properties.certificates[0] does not give me any output

Thank you again for all this help, i appreciate it more than you know!

Comment: so the `.certificates` property outputs what you need? can you just use it?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following [these](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37431.exporting-azure-app-service-certificates.aspx) technet instructions and it gave me the PFX.